# How can I preview open ports in the VS Code Sidebar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any extension which can open a preview of the Open Port inside the VS Code like GitPod IDE does... It can help developers so that instead of toggling between browser and editor, we can lok side by side...

Answer (score 0):

You can use and extension like [Browser Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=auchenberg.vscode-browser-preview).

Also you can also have preview and hot reload without any installation by running browser-sync like this:

```
$ npx browser-sync start -s -w
```

Just make sure to run the command at the same level as your index.html.